# c++ adding comma separated values

Tags: c++, csv, stringstream, atoi

Trying to add together some comma separated values from a string. I feel like I will need to remove the commas. Is this a case for stringstream?

```
string str = "4, 3, 2"
//Get individual numbers
//Add them together
//output the sum. Prints 9
```

Comment: You are right. One solution is std::istringstream in conjunction with std::getline

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `istringstream` with `getline` in a while loop to split (tokenize) the string around commas.
Then simply use `std::stoi` to convert each string token into an integer, and add that number to the sum. `std::stoi` discards any whitespace characters within the string input.

```
std::string str = "4, 3, 2";
std::istringstream ss(str);

int sum = 0;
std::string token;
while(std::getline(ss, token, ',')) {
    sum += std::stoi(token);
}
std::cout << "The sum: " << sum;
```